# I'm finding troubles to define the options (client & admin) in the userType attribute at user model. Any suggestions with the syntax?

Tags: javascript, express, sequelize.js

I'm finding troubles to define the options (client & admin) in the userType attribute at user model. Any suggestions with the syntax!?

**making context this is where I'm stuck right now**

```
   module.exports = (sequelize)=>{
     sequelize.define('user', {
       id: {...},
       name: {...},
       lastName: {...},
       email: {...},
       password: {...},
       userType: {
         type: S.INTEGER,
         allowNull: false,
         defaultValue: 0,
         validate: {
           min: {
             args: [0],
           },
           max: {
             args: [1],
           }
         }
       }
     })
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use enum type and pass the options in the values *(edited)***

```
    module.exports = (sequelize)=>{
         sequelize.define('user', {
           id: {...},
           name: {...},
           lastName: {...},
           email: {...},
           password: {...},
           userType: {
             type: S.ENUM,
             allowNull: false,
             defaultValue: 'client',
             values: ['client', 'admin'],
             validate: {
               notNull: {
                 msg: 'The type of user must be defined'
               }
             }
           }         
         })
       }
```